# Using ccd OpenVPN user can connect , but can't access other devices

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm using ccd OpenVPN settings to make static keys for each users.

My Server config looks like

```
cat openvpn.conf
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
user nobody
group nogroup
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
client-to-client
push "route 10.8.0.0  255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.25
management localhost 7505
push "redirect-gateway def1"
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
#set the dns servers
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
log-append /var/log/openvpn
comp-lzo
```

and ccd for user looks like

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.3.15 10.8.3.15
```

When default configuration clients can be accessible from any VPN network device and it can access any device on network , client this ccd configured client can not be accessed from net and it can not access / ping any VPN network device.

I've browsed around , found similar problems , and changed configuration according to them , but it did not help me.

How can I make this ccd client to access other devices and that this client would be accessible from other OpenVPN devices?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html):

> Each pair of ifconfig-push addresses represent the virtual client and
>   server IP endpoints. They must be taken from successive /30 subnets in
>   order to be compatible with Windows clients and the TAP-Windows
>   driver. Specifically, the last octet in the IP address of each
>   endpoint pair must be taken from this set:

Fix your ccd config:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.3.15 10.8.3.15
```

Since you have /30 networks, `10.8.3.15` is a broadcast address for `10.8.3.12/30`, and cannot be used as a client IP.

Comment: I'm kind a newbie ,I've even read this part , but did not get the point of it.
Do I have to take range of 30 address or pairs like it is shown in example ([1 2] "ifconfig-push 10.8.3.1 10.8.3.2" , [5 , 6] "ifconfig-push 10.8.3.5 10.8.3.6"). I've tried it , but it did not help me.Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: Ok , I found solution here : http://superuser.com/questions/663024/using-ccd-openvpn-user-can-connect-but-cant-access-other-devices